# Finitely generated module $M$ over principal ideal domain splits into direct sum of $M_\text{tors}$ and $M' \subset M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain and $M$ be an finitely generated $R$-module.

The torsion module $M_{\text{tors}}$ is defined as
$$
M_{\text{tors}} := \left\{ m \in M \;|\; \text{there is}\; a\in R \setminus \{0\} \;\text{with}\; am = 0 \right\}.
$$

I want to show that there is a $R$-submodule $M' \subset M$ with $M = M' \oplus M_{\text{tors}}$.

**What I tried:**
I know that

$$
M \cong R^r \oplus R/(a_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus R/(a_s),
$$

for some $r \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $a_1, \dots a_s \in R \setminus \{0\}$.

It is also clear that $R/(a_i)$ are fields, since $(a_i)$ is maximal because we are in a principal ideal domain.

However, I don't know how to show that $R^r \cong M_\text{tors}$.

Comment: Your approach appears to be deeply confused. Firstly, it is not true that the $R/(a_{i})$ should be fields; it is true that prime ideals in a PID are maximal, but all you have required is that $a_{1}, ..., a_{s}$ are nonzero. (Consider, e.g., the PID $R = \mathbb{Z}$, and the principal ideal $(4)$; certainly, $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, since $(4)$ is not a prime ideal.) Secondly, it does not matter whether the $R/(a_{i})$ are fields, since you are interested in their structure as $R$-modules, not rings. You can see that any element of $R/(a_{i})$ is annihilated by  $a_{i}$...

Comment: ...and so elements of $R/(a_{i})$ (as identified with elements of $M$) correspond with *torsion* $R$-elements. In short, with your approach, you have things backwards: $R^{r}$ corresponds with the torsion-free part of $M$, not the torsion part, and $M_{\mathrm{tors}}$ should correspond with $R/(a_{1}) \oplus \cdots \oplus R/(a_{s})$. More generally, I don't know where your question comes from, so I can't say anything about the context in which it arose, but using the classification theorem for f.g. modules over a PID here seems odd. Indeed, typically one begins the classification for...

Comment: ...modules over a PID by first showing that $M$ decomposes into a direct sum of its torsion and torsion-free parts. Hence, using the classification theorem might yield a swift answer to this question, but doing so would be (IMO) philosophically backwards, unless your proof for the classification theorem avoids this decomposition early on.